# Will glfw always report key callback before char callback?

Tags: glfw

A small test:

```
$ ./test
OpenGL version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.57.02
Key callback
Char callback
Key callback
```

Is it guaranteed that "Key callback" always occurs before "Char callback", or is this a potential Hyrum's Law pitfall.

Comment: Regardless of what the manual says or doesn't say, I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't find anything related to the order of these events in the manual, but it should be possible to group them anyways if desired, right?

Comment: What do you mean? You're asking if one arrives if and only if the other one does, in the same frame?

Comment: I mean, that if I set a callback for both of these events, I will obviously catch two events per key-down. It looks like I only get one for Key-up though. The question is if the order of two callbacks is guaranteed.

Comment: Then the answer is the same, I wouldn't count on it. Especially since as you say the manual doesn't mention it. It wouldn't even count on them arriving in pairs.

Comment: Well, that counts as an answer for now.